# Kyocera job accounting and document box

Tags: printing

I work at school and we have many XP machines. A few machines I have converted to various light Linux versions.

The problem I am having is with the Kyocera printers. We use job accounting and the kyocera drivers have to be setup to prompt for an account code in order to print.

One location the problem is even more challenging. 
The user is prompted for a code, but the document is not printed. The kyocera stores the document to that users document box on the kyocera. 
The driver on the windows machine at time of install is given a box number that corresponds to one user account/code on the kyocera.

Any ideals?
Thanks,
JK

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. The only help that I found is for windows...http://www.conewago.k12.pa.us/uploads/2/1/2/9/21299964/how_to_turn_on_kyocera_job_accounting.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem for a 4505ci.
Solved with this help : http://abaqueiro.blogspot.fr/2011/07/set-up-kyocera-mita-1820-in-ubuntu-1004.html

Job accounting are abled in default PDD driver file but only 0~30 account ID are in the list.
You have to modify the PDD file used by your printer. For me it was like this :

Replace :

```
*KmManagment Default/Inactif: ""
*KmManagment MG00000000/00000000: "(00000000) statusdict /setmanagementnumber get exec"
*KmManagment MG00000001/00000001: "(00000001) statusdict /setmanagementnumber get exec"
*KmManagment MG00000002/00000002: "(00000002) statusdict /setmanagementnumber get exec"
*KmManagment MG00000003/00000003: "(00000003) statusdict /setmanagementnumber get exec"
*KmManagment MG00000004/00000004: "(00000004) statusdict /setmanagementnumber get exec"
*KmManagment MG00000005/00000005: "(00000005) statusdict /setmanagementnumber get exec"
....
*?KmManagment: ""
```

By :

```
*KmManagment MG00000000/00000000: "(00000000) statusdict /setmanagementnumber get exec"
*KmManagment 4835/4835: "(4835) statusdict /setmanagementnumber get exec"
*?KmManagment: ""
```

I don't know exactly wich part is informative and wich one is important so I just replaced any number by my account.

For example, this didn't work for me :

```
MG00004835/00004835: "(00004835)
```

But this worked perfectly :

```
*KmManagment 4835/4835: "(4835) statusdict /setmanagementnumber get exec"
```

I think a replacement with a text box option, instead of a select list, would be a most interesting solution...