# Sending Job ID to Kyocera Printer

Tags: printing, cups-lpd

I recently upgraded my Ubuntu 16.04 to 17.10 (I performed a clean install). When installing the same drive / software (kyodialog3.pt_0.5-0_amd64.deb) used in the previous version, I have not been able to open the software to configure the work account, maybe due to unconsciousness, I really do not know ...

**So, how could I set the job ID to be sent to Kyocera Taskalfa 255 at the time of printing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much searching, I just performed the following steps:

1. Install the kyodialog3.pt_0.5-0_amd64.deb drive (or your printer's specification - http://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.com)
2. Open the file by using **Vim**, /etc/cups/ppd/Kyocera-TASKalfa-255-KPDL.ppd - **IMPORTANT:** I ​​do not know exactly why, but do not use Sublime or Gedit because they can not display the contents of the ppd file.
3. Look for the line

   ```
   *% KmManagment
   *OpenUI *KmManagment/Job accounting: PickOne
   *OrderDependency: 60 AnySetup *KmManagment
   *DefaultKmManagment: Default
   *KmManagment Default/Off: "0"
   *KmManagment MG00000000/00000000: "(00000000) statusdict /setmanagementnumber get exec"
   *KmManagment MG00000001/00000001: "(00000001) statusdict /setmanagementnumber get exec"

   ...

   *?KmManagment: "0"
   *End
   *CloseUI: *KmManagment
   ```
4. Change the line below by entering the ID of your work account

   ```
   *DefaultKmManagment: MG00000000
   *KmManagment Default/Off: "0"
   *KmManagment MG00000000/YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID: "(YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID) statusdict /setmanagementnumber get exec"
   ```
5. Restart the cups service

   ```
   sudo service cups restart
   ```

I hope I have helped.

References

http://pengelly-info.blogspot.com.br/2011/10/printer-setup-for-linux.html
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.printing.cups.general/20509
http://abaqueiro.blogspot.com.br/2011/07/set-up-kyocera-mita-1820-in-ubuntu-1004.html
[Kyocera job accounting and document box](https://askubuntu.com/questions/514791/kyocera-job-accounting-and-document-box)

:)